# Am I understanding Pascal's law the right way?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, pressure, fluid-statics

I'm just intuitively trying to figure this out, so I would like for someone to see, if I'm understanding pressure transfer right. In a solid an external force acting upon it gets equally transferred through it unless the solid has different cross sectional areas, since increasing the area would decrease the pressure at that point of the solid and vice verse, but in a liquid in which molecules are free to move the pressure at bigger cross sectional areas does not decrease, since the increasing of the cross sectional area is accompanied by a bigger number of molecules which are found at that region and so it balances out, in a solid no additional molecules can get into the bigger cross sectional area to accompany for this drop in pressure.

Answer (score 1):

If we compare a liquid and a solid in a similar pressure situation, the result can be also the same.

Suppose a spherical thick steel container, with a hole for entrance where a piston can be installed. If we fill it with liquid lead, and press the liquid with the piston, the pressure of course spreads equally along the liquid.

But if we keep the pressure constant to avoid any gap between the steel walls (due to the foundry shrinkage) and the interior lead during the solidification, we can say the same for the solid lead: the pressure spreads equally along the solid lead.